# How can I publish my code on GitHub without giving away my secret credentials?

Tags: python-3.x, github

I'd like to upload my discord bot to Github. However, The code is very simple and small, so I put everything in only one .py file, including the token.

How do I "hide" the token when uploading to GitHub?

I've read some questions about it, but they are mostly related to discord.js

Comment: This is not related to any programming language at all, this question also doesn't suit this site

Answer (score 2):

In the folder with your other files, create a new file called `token.txt`. In this file, add your token as plain text without any quotes.
This is how your `token.txt` file should look like

```py
# token.txt file
ODA2MjU4MjQ0NzU3NjE4Njg4.YBm0gQ.rgvGyi-TC77Mb9P57BIBrTqicWs # this token is null and void
```

Then, if you haven't already, create a `.gitignore` file, and in that file, add `token.txt`. This will let GitHub know that the file should be ignored, since it ignores any files that are specified in `.gitignore`.
Then, go to the bottom of your main `.py` file and enter this:

```py
with open('token.txt') as f:
    TOKEN = f.readline()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This will open the textfile, read in the token, assign it to `TOKEN`, and then it'll close the textfile.
Make sure to `git add`, `git commit`, and `git push` only after you've done these steps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have your token in plain text in your bot.py file. Use environment variables on your PC so that it's stored separate from the bot's code. You can even use a .txt file and read it in. Just don't upload the token to github.

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable to store your bot token and add it to `.gitignore`. This will require you to install the dotenv library by using
`pip install python-dotenv`.

Create a `.env` file and add your token here.

```
TOKEN = 'your token here'
```

Pass the token to the client in your main script

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
import os

load_dotenv()

client = discord.Client()
client.run(os.environ.get('TOKEN'))
```